# How to use a third-party Javascript library in Jest in a react-typescript application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have created a react-typescript application using `create-react-app`. I have a class named `Converter` that uses a third-party JS module library with starting code as:

```
var ZapModule = function(ZapModule) {
...
```

I can use this library fine by adding it to the index.html file and then creating a `var zp = ZapModule()` but can't seem to use it in my Jest tests for the `Converter` class. The tests fail with a `ZapModule is not defined` error. How can I include this Javascript module to work with the tests?

Comment: Did you try var ZapModule = require('your library')

Comment: Where should I put that statement?

Comment: Note that the ZapModule is not a node module

Comment: Can you put your test code here?